# What does おは顕示欲 mean?

Tags: meaning

Caption on a picture of a woman with nice dress

Other sentence usage for different photos includes the following:

1. 顕示欲の出涸らし
2. おやすみ顕示欲
3. 隠し切れない顕示欲
4. 溢れ出る顕示欲

Note: The dress is not sexy nor revealing, but generally casual. Is the woman trying to show-off her clothes, or is she trying to say 'Do I look nice on this dress?"

Caption on twitter page as below:
https://twitter.com/suzukisakiika/status/1249479824260730881

Comment: In normal sense, おは顕示欲 is a nonsense word. Could I see the real thing you're talking about?

Answer (score 3):

おは顕示欲 is not a word itself, but I kind of understand what it says.

First, おは is an extra shortened form of おはよう. It can be used alone for super casual morning greeting, or as a part of playful portmanteau like [おはこんばんちは](https://moto-neta.com/anime/ohakonbanchiwa/). I think it is the latter in this case.

The second part 顕示欲 is a long story. It is not an easy word, and was nor common until a (quite) while ago when experts pointed out that [modern SNSes (including Twitter) were functioning as some kind of "self-esteem porn"](https://ddnavi.com/news/179437/a/). Keywords highlighted at that time were such as 承認欲求 (Maslow's *[esteem needs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs)*) and 自己顕示欲 ("desire of self-display"), which soon became buzzwords mostly with a negative meaning. There might be similar terms used same way in the English-speaking world, but I am not familiar with it.

As those words gain popularity, people start to use them as a joke, as much as saying "Hi, I shamelessly need likes so do it!" Given that this is a Twitter post, the author must be fond of using the word in this way. So, in this case, the literal-ish translation would be like "morning-ostentation" or effectively saying "Morning! See my attention-seeking!"

Comment: "Exhibitionism" is probably the best English equivalent for 自己顕示欲, though not a perfect one. (It can also mean something like 露出症, and even some native speakers may be under the impression that is the primary or only meaning.)

Comment: @Nanigashi Thanks for your input. I kind of found an authoritative equivalent for 承認欲求 but not for 自己顕示欲 (I don't know even if it has or not).

Answer (score 2):

Let's go part-by-part.  Here's [a definition I found of 顕示欲](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A1%95%E7%A4%BA%E6%AC%B2) on weblio:

> 何かを誇示したい、認められたい、などという欲望のこと。「自己顕示欲」などという具合に使う。

So it's essentially a desire to be seen.  From the fact that another example you found is おやすみ顕示欲 and that many of the replies to your tweet say お早うございます, I think we can infer that おは is short for おはよう.

So I think this if this were in English she'd be saying something like "morning mood" or "good morning, how do I look?"